# SharePoint Multiple Check-in

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to check-in multiple files in SharePoint 2013 at once?

Is there a limitation of files that you can check-in at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Site Setting > Content and Structure to check in multiple files at once.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information YogaPanda. I could now check-in the files.

Comment: I would also like to ask if the reason why you cannot check-in multiple files on not going to Site Setting > Content and Structure is because of the versioning setting? 

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check-in button is not in the ribbon that users can easily check-in multiple files at once. I feel M$ tend to hide more advanced functions in site settings. If I really need to give a reasonable answer for that is to avoid error. Check-in requires users to fill in all the required metadata,  otherwise, it will cause issue and error. In order to avoid that, M$ just simply hide the function (same as bulk download.)

Comment: Please vote my answer or mark it as the right answer if my answer is helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do multiple check-in but at once only 100 items can be checked-in.

Answer (score 0):

Our tenant has been updated to the new look and now we are unable to check in multiple files.
In the "classic view" we were able to check in multiple files without issue which is important functionality when we are uploading multiple documents into a library with check in/out enabled.
This "restriction" is confirmed in the small note at the bottom of https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-out-or-check-in-files-in-a-document-library-acce24cd-ab39-4fcf-9c4d-1ce3050dc602 which says the solution is to "return to classic view", check them in and then come back to the new view.